# Hiding subview in CollectionViewCell doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift

I have a progression layer on my `CollectionViewCell` that shows the download progress, and I want to hide it when the download is completed. But somehow, it doesn't hide when it enter the if condition where my views are suppose to hide.

I've tried putting the whole thing in a `DispatchQueue.main.async`, no success. I've tried also putting a `self.setNeedsDisplay()` or `self.layoutIfNeeded()`. I even tried `removeFromSuperLayer` None of those worked, I'm kinda running out of solution here. My layers/views does appears when the download starts, when reaching completion, nothing happens.

What am I missing, this should be easy T_T

```
class DownloadableCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var bgPath: UIBezierPath!
    var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer!
    var progressLayer: CAShapeLayer!

    var controlButton: UIButton!
    var lockIcon: UIImageView!

    var frameCenter: CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y: self.frame.height/2)
    }

    private var progress: Float = 0.0 {
        didSet(newValue) {

            progressLayer.strokeEnd = CGFloat(newValue)
            if newValue == 1 {
                progressLayer.isHidden = true
                controlButton.isHidden = true
                lockIcon.isHidden = true
            } else {
                progressLayer.isHidden = false
                controlButton.isHidden = false
            }
        }
    }

    public func setProgress(progress: Float) {
        self.progress = progress
    }
```

Setting the progress is done in the `TableViewCell` which is holding a `CollectionView`

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let audioItem = self.listItems[indexPath.row]
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! AudioCollectionViewCell

        if audioItem.isDownloaded {
            // Go to next screen
            print("Downloaded already!")
        } else {

            self.downloadAudio(audioPath: audioItem.imageName) { (task) in
                task.observe(.progress) { snapshot in
                    let progress = Float(snapshot.progress!.fileCompletedCount ?? 1) / Float(snapshot.progress!.fileTotalCount ?? 1)
                    cell.setProgress(progress: progress)
                    if progress == 1 {
                        self.listItems[indexPath.row].isDownloaded = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So calling progress with a value of 1, not in the context of your download, will hide progressLayer correctly? If so, provide the code which sets the value of progress.

Comment: Use `didSet`, not `willSet`. Or change `if progress == 1` to `if newValue == 1`.

Comment: @FJdeBrienne Updated my post to add that

Comment: @rmaddy Just tried both, none worked

Comment: I know you said you tried `DispatchQueue.main.async` but I think it's required here. You could breakpoint on the line `self.listItems(indexPath.row].isDownloaded=true` and verify what thread you're on. If it's not the main thread, you definitely to wrap that in a main thread `sync/async` call.

Comment: Also, print the `cell` variable to see if it's not `nil` when the progress completes. It should be retained by the closure but, who knows...

Comment: Another idea, since I don't know the code behind `downloadAudio()`, print the progress from your `DownloadableCollectionViewCell` as it gets updated. Does it receive a value that is not 1 **after** having received 1?

Comment: try to hide it in your `didSelectItemAt` in `if progress == 1 {}`

Comment: I called the hiding in the didSelectItemAt finally, it seems to work... Im not sure why since it was running in the main thread when I was calling setProgress()

Comment: That because you reuse cell and if you want change some cell you need to change cell by index path